# Html extension in VB.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I implemented a Module using VB.NET in order to handle localization in an MVC .NET application.

However, when I try to call the extension method LanguageSelectorLink from my view, it`s required to provide something for the first parameter of type HtmlHelper. In all C# samples I found on the Internet, this parameter is never provided and it seems to work fine.

@App_Code.LanguageSelectorLink(Nothing, "en-CA", "[English]", "English", Nothing)

Did I miss a step? Can anybody help me?

Imports System.Threading

Namespace App_Code

```
Public Module SwitchLanguageHelper
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function LanguageUrl(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper,
                                       ByVal cultureName As String,
                                       Optional ByVal languageRouteName As String = "lang",
                                       Optional ByVal strictSelected As Boolean = False) As Language
        'Set the input language to lower
        cultureName = cultureName.ToLower()

        'retrieve the route values from the view context
        Dim routeValues = New RouteValueDictionary(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values)

        'copy the query strings into the route values to generate the link
        Dim queryString = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString

        For Each key In queryString
            If (Not (IsNothing(queryString(key))) And
               Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString(key)))) Then
                If (routeValues.ContainsKey(key)) Then
                    routeValues(key) = queryString(key)
                Else
                    routeValues.Add(key, queryString(key))
                End If

            End If
        Next

        Dim actionName = routeValues("action").ToString()
        Dim controllerName = routeValues("controller").ToString()

        'set the language into route values
        routeValues(languageRouteName) = cultureName

        'generate the language specify url
        Dim urlHelper = New UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection)
        Dim url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("Localization", routeValues)

        'check whether the current thread ui culture is this language
        Dim current_lang_name = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()
        Dim isSelected As Boolean

        If (strictSelected) Then
            current_lang_name = cultureName
        Else
            current_lang_name.StartsWith(cultureName)
        End If

        isSelected = current_lang_name

        Dim language As Language = New Language()

        language.Url = url
        language.ActionName = actionName
        language.ControllerName = controllerName
        language.RouteValues = routeValues
        language.IsSelected = isSelected

        Return language
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function LanguageSelectorLink(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal cultureName As String, ByVal selectedText As String, ByVal unselectedText As String, ByVal htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object), Optional ByVal languageRouteName As String = "lang", _
                                         Optional ByVal strictSelected As Boolean = False) As MvcHtmlString
        Dim language = helper.LanguageUrl(cultureName, languageRouteName, strictSelected)
        Dim link = helper.RouteLink(If(language.IsSelected, selectedText, unselectedText), "Localization", language.RouteValues, htmlAttributes)

        Return link
    End Function


End Module
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is add two extension methods to the `HtmlHelper` class. The `ByVal helper as HtmlHelper` is passed implicitly as an instance of the `HtmlHelper` class when you use these methods.

This is how you use them in a view:

```vb
@Imports YourApplicationName.AppCode

@Html.LanguageSelectorLink("en-CA", "[English]", "English", Nothing)
```

Hope this helps.